# C# Unable to compile "CS0103: The name 'Gutils' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: php

When I try compile this Class via command prompt with csc.exe each time got error "'Gutils' does not exist in the current context". What is wrong? How would one go about solving this problem? Im using .Net Framework 3.5.

This Class should encode/decode PlayerID, UserID, ProductID and Timestamp:

```
namespace GameSpy.Util
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;

    public class LoginTicket
    {
        private static byte[] LOGIN_TICKET_KEY = new byte[] { 0x8b, 0xad, 0x91, 0xac, 0xeb, 3, 0x71, 0xb9, 150, 0x53, 0xa8, 0x33, 0xe4, 0xf5, 0x2c, 0x2c };

        private static ushort Crc16(byte[] input)
        {
            int num = 0;
            foreach (byte num2 in input)
            {
                num = ((byte) (num >> 8)) | (num << 8);
                num ^= num2;
                num ^= ((byte) (num & 255)) >> 4;
                num ^= (num << 8) << 4;
                num ^= ((num & 255) << 4) << 1;
            }
            return (ushort) num;
        }

        public static string CreateLoginTicket(int userID, int profileID, ushort productID)
        {
            RijndaelManaged managed = new RijndaelManaged();
            managed.IV = new byte[16];
            managed.KeySize = 128;
            managed.Key = LOGIN_TICKET_KEY;
            managed.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            managed.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(16);
            CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream, managed.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream(16);
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(output);
            writer.Write(Gutils.UTCSeconds());
            writer.Write(userID);
            writer.Write(profileID);
            writer.Write(productID);
            writer.Write(Crc16(output.ToArray()));
            stream2.Write(output.ToArray(), 0, (int) output.Length);
            stream2.FlushFinalBlock();
            return B64Helper.StandardBase64ToSafeBase64(B64Helper.EncodeToString(stream.ToArray()));
        }

        public static void DecodeLoginTicket(string ticket, out int userID, out int profileID, out ushort productID, out DateTime timeStamp)
        {
            byte[] buffer = B64Helper.DecodeFromString(B64Helper.SafeBase64ToStandardBase64(ticket));
            RijndaelManaged managed = new RijndaelManaged();
            managed.IV = new byte[16];
            managed.KeySize = 128;
            managed.Key = LOGIN_TICKET_KEY;
            managed.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            managed.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer.Length);
            CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream, managed.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            stream2.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            stream2.FlushFinalBlock();
            stream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            int seconds = reader.ReadInt32();
            userID = reader.ReadInt32();
            profileID = reader.ReadInt32();
            productID = reader.ReadUInt16();
            ushort num2 = reader.ReadUInt16();
            stream.SetLength(14L);
            ushort num3 = Crc16(stream.ToArray());
            if (num2 != num3)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException("Invalid CRC value");
            }
            timeStamp = Gutils.UTCSecondsToDateTime(seconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is another piece of code:

```
namespace GameSpy.Util
{
    using System;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;

    public class B64Helper
    {
        public static byte[] Decode(byte[] inputBuffer)
        {
            return Decode(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);
        }

        public static byte[] Decode(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount)
        {
            FromBase64Transform transform = new FromBase64Transform();
            return transform.TransformFinalBlock(inputBuffer, inputOffset, inputCount);
        }

        public static byte[] DecodeFromString(string input)
        {
            return Decode(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input));
        }

        public static byte[] Encode(byte[] inputBuffer)
        {
            return Encode(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);
        }

        public static byte[] Encode(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount)
        {
            ToBase64Transform transform = new ToBase64Transform();
            int num = (inputCount / 3) * 4;
            if ((inputCount % 3) != 0)
            {
                num += 4;
            }
            byte[] outputBuffer = new byte[num];
            int num2 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; num2 < inputCount; i += 4)
            {
                int num5 = Math.Min(3, inputCount - num2);
                if (num5 == 3)
                {
                    int num4 = transform.TransformBlock(inputBuffer, inputOffset + num2, num5, outputBuffer, i);
                }
                else
                {
                    transform.TransformFinalBlock(inputBuffer, inputOffset + num2, num5).CopyTo(outputBuffer, i);
                }
                num2 += 3;
            }
            return outputBuffer;
        }

        public static string EncodeToString(byte[] inputBuffer)
        {
            return EncodeToString(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);
        }

        public static string EncodeToString(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encode(inputBuffer, inputOffset, inputCount);
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        }

        public static string SafeBase64ToStandardBase64(string b64str)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(b64str);
            builder.Replace('_', '=');
            builder.Replace('[', '+');
            builder.Replace(']', '/');
            return builder.ToString();
        }

        public static string StandardBase64ToSafeBase64(string b64str)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(b64str);
            builder.Replace('=', '_');
            builder.Replace('+', '[');
            builder.Replace('/', ']');
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Second part of code:

```
namespace GameSpy.Util
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.IO;

    public sealed class Gutils
    {
        public static DateTime UTCSecondsToDateTime(int seconds)
        {
            return TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) + new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds));
        }
    }
}

        public static uint UTCSeconds()
    {
        TimeSpan span = (TimeSpan) (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(0x7b2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        return (uint) span.TotalSeconds;
    }
```

Files paths:

[image]

Comment: ... And what is `Gutils` ... ?

Comment: And what is `Gutils`? Where is it declared?

Comment: Are all these classes in the same assembly?

Comment: Please tell us in what .cs-files, projects/assemblies these classes are and show the command line you use for csc.exe.

Comment: So are all the above classes inside `LoginTicket.cs`? I guess (but am not sure) you have to tell csc.exe _all_ input files.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell `csc.exe` which files you want to compile. Since your `Gutil` class is obviously in `gutils.cs` and not in `LoginTicket.cs` the compiler can't find it when you only compile `LoginTicket.cs`.

Try this:

```
csc.exe LoginTicket.cs Gutils.cs
```

or even

```
csc.exe *.cs
```

Use

```
csc.exe /?
```

for more command line options (like recursing through subdirectories etc...)

---

Further reading: [Command-line build with csc.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe)